# I am trying to implement an html link to open up local files from my hardrive on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I use the file:/// protocol followed by my file location and for some reason I keep getting the same: "Webpage is not found" error.

Eg: `<a href="‪file:///C:\Desktop\Projects\Webpage.htm"><li>HOME</li> </a>`

Comment: Why not just use relative links? e.g <a href="Projects/Webpage.htm">Content</a> (assuming your file is on Desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax works for me:

```
<a href="‪file:///C:/Desktop/Projects/Webpage.htm">Home</a>
```

Also putting `<li>` inside of `<a>` is not valid HTML, because `<li>` should be the only element of list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`). The correct way is to put `<a>` inside of `<li>.`

Comment: Thanks, my slashes were messed up.